# Access some values in php variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array variable $var.
When I var_dump($var), it shows the following:

```
array(2) {
   [0] => array(3) {
         ["name"] => string(7) "Ferrari" 
         ["speed"] => int(120)
         ["isActive"] => bool(true)
         }array(3) {
         ["name"] => string(7) "Porsche" 
         ["speed"] => int(100)
         ["isActive"] => bool(false)
         }
}
```

The question is: 
I want to access these values. For example, i want to save the speed value of Ferrari into a variable $speed.

Something like check every element of array,
If "name" = Ferrari,
Set $speed= corresponding int value of  choosen element of array.

What is the syntax of this in PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried?  It's simple array and loop syntax that you're asking for.

Comment: You use a loop for that. `foreach ($yourarray as $element)` then the $element varialbe is your key value array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$speed = null;
foreach ($var as $car) {
    if ($car['name'] == 'Ferrari') {
        $speed = $car['speed'];
    }
}
echo $speed;
```

Would be more reusable if you'll extend the array `$var`.

You can find basics of PHP here: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the value from the array. Check isset to make sure the value exists if you want.

```
$speed = (isset($var[0]['speed'])) ? $var[0]['speed'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

pls try this :

```
$speed = 0;
if (isset($var[0]["name"]) && isset($var[0]["speed"]) && $var[0]["name"]=="Ferrari"){
    $speed = $var[0]["speed"];
}
```